# webkitgtk build ( WebP libraries were not found when I have installed the webp library)

Tags: cmake, webp, webkitgtk

when I build the webkitgtk-2.34.6 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, using the following command:(Follow the official documentation)[https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingGtk]

```
cmake -DPORT=GTK -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -GNinja
```

"WebP libraries were not found" error appear:

```
-- The CMake build type is: RelWithDebInfo
-- Could NOT find Ruby (missing: RUBY_INCLUDE_DIR RUBY_LIBRARY RUBY_CONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR) (found suitable version "2.7.0", minimum required is "1.9")
-- Enabling ccache: Couldn't find ccache program. Not enabling it.
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-fdiagnostics-color=always
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-fdiagnostics-color=always - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-fdiagnostics-color=always
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-fdiagnostics-color=always - Success
-- Found the following HarfBuzz libraries:
--  HarfBuzz (required): /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so
--  ICU (required): /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz-icu.so
-- Found the following ICU libraries:
--   data (required)
--   i18n (required)
--   uc (required)
-- The following WebP libraries were not found:
--  WebP (required)
--  demux (required)
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find WebP (missing: WebP_INCLUDE_DIR WebP_LIBRARY
  _WebP_REQUIRED_LIBS_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  Source/cmake/FindWebP.cmake:133 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  Source/cmake/WebKitFindPackage.cmake:105 (_find_package)
  Source/cmake/OptionsGTK.cmake:25 (find_package)
  Source/cmake/WebKitCommon.cmake:220 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/crz/SerialscreenWebkit/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/crz/SerialscreenWebkit/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

but I have installed the webp library using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install -y webp
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
webp is already the newest version (0.6.1-2ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
```

Comment: The package providing the webp **library** is named [libwebp6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libwebp6). Because you need to compile against this library, you need also "development" package [libwebp-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libwebp-dev).

Answer (score 0):

use this command

```sh
sudo apt install libwebp-dev
```